# VHDL - read HEX file

Tags: file, file-io, hex, vhdl

In [VHDL - init std_logic_vector array from HEX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164216/vhdl-init-std-logic-vector-array-from-hex-file/) i have almost solved RAM initialization from HEX file. But the reading from file as is seems not working.

```
function ram_init(filename : string) return memory_array is
    variable temp : memory_array;
    file file_ptr : text;
    variable line_line : line;
    variable line_text : string(1 to 14);
    variable tmp_hexnum : string(1 to 2);
    variable lines_read : integer := 0;
    begin
        file_open(file_ptr,filename,READ_MODE);
        while (lines_read < 32 and not endfile(file_ptr)) loop
            readline (file_ptr,line_line);
            read (line_line,line_text);
            tmp_hexnum := line_text(10 to 11);
            temp(lines_read) := hex_to_bin(tmp_hexnum);
            lines_read := lines_read + 1;
        end loop;
        file_close(file_ptr);
    return temp;
end function;
signal ram : memory_array := ram_init(filename=>"../RAM.HEX");
```

If I set tmp_hexnum to e.g. "0A", it's OK, but reading from file do not fill the RAM.

Can you please check the file part for me?

Comment: If you "Report" in the while loop on the substring and the converted value, are they both correct?

Comment: The problem is, this code does not work - all RAM positions are initiated to "00". When I set tmp_hexnum to e.g. "0A", it's OK and all RAM positions are initiated to this value, so converting via my hex_to_bin function is OK.

Comment: So the next step is to "report" each line you read from file. Is that what you expect?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "report". But what I would like is to loop through the file and from each line extract substring containing 10th and 11th character (which contains the hexadecimal value in my .HEX file).

Comment: Read about Assert and Report in any book on VHDL.

Comment: Tried to check file_open status, but it is OPEN_OK even if I fill non existing file. The read line_text seems to be "".