# How to subtract two hexadecimal numbers in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am reading two hex numbers from a text file and I want to be able to subtract the two numbers and place the result into another variable how would I go about doing this? Is it possible to make a function to do this that I can then place in a package file and reference so that my code is more readable and less cluttered?

many thanks,

Comment: It's not clear whether you have already managed to read the hex values from the file. Also, questions should generally be in the form of a specific problem, with example code that people can look at to try to diagnose your issue.

Comment: Converting from hex strings to numbers has already been discussed, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164216/vhdl-init-std-logic-vector-array-from-hex-file

Answer (score 0):

For conversion of `line` to `unsigned`, VHDL-2008 provides a `hread` procedure in then `numeric_bit` package.  A function that takes `string` and returns `natural` could look like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;
library std;
use std.textio.all;
...
function hex_to_nat(s : string) return natural is
  variable line_v : line;
  variable value_v : unsigned(4 * s'length - 1 downto 0);  -- Bits to match value in hex
begin
  line_v := new string'(s);
  hread(line_v, value_v);  -- Assertion in case of conversion error
  deallocate(line_v);  -- Avoid memory leak
  return to_integer(value_v);  -- Assertion in case of conversion error
end function;
```

If the text read from the file is already of `line` type, then just use the `hread` procedure directly.